# How to pull integers from the middle of SQL query results

Tags: sql, replace, trim

I have a SQL table returning results as follows:

```
XY_4_**505543**_1227_1499547620
```

I am attempting to pull the bolded only.
I have tried a mix of `replace('XY_4_','')` and `len()` with a -16. But I think I am approaching this wrong.

I was hoping to use something like the following, but replace doesn't allow wildcards:

```
select replace(replace(column, 'XY_4_','')'_%%%%_%%%%%%%%%%','') from table
```

Comment: What is your expected results?  Is it `4` or `4_505543_1227_1499547620`?

Comment: You need to look at regex replace for this. You want to use a wildcard, replace doesn't allow them

Comment: @mtr.web I am trying to pull out the "505543"

Comment: @cramopy Looking into regex now

Comment: @Gjack, does your result always have the same format?

Comment: @chaosifier yes, it always has the same format XX_X_YYYYYY_XXXX_XXXXXXXXXX. As where I need the Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your desired output string always begins from 6th character and contains 6 characters in total, you could use the SUBSTRING function to get the desired result.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 6, 6) FROM table;
```

Where the first parameter is the column name, the second is the start index (1 based) and the last parameter is the number of characters to retrieve.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I am still sorting out how to do this via regular expression as well because in the future it may change length.

Answer (score 0):

This should help -

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('XY_4_**505543**_1227_1499547620','\**([0-9]*)\*',1,1,NULL,1) AS VAL
FROM
    DUAL;
```

Output -

```
"VAL"
"505543"
```